# In Puppeteer, how do I get the innerHTML of a selector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, innerhtml, puppeteer

At the moment, I'm trying the following:

```
const element = await page.$("#myElement");
const html = element.innerHTML;
```

I'm expecting the HTML to be printed, but instead I'm getting `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you just print `element`?

Answer (score 7):

#### page.evaluate():

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of an element:

```
const inner_html = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#myElement').innerHTML);

console.log(inner_html);
```

#### elementHandle.getProperty() / .jsonValue():

Alternatively, if you must use [`page.$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector), you can access the `innerHTML` using a combination of [`elementHandle.getProperty()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) and [`elementHandle.jsonValue()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlejsonvalue):

```
const inner_html = await (await (await page.$('#myElement')).getProperty('innerHTML')).jsonValue();

console.log(inner_html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `page.$eval` to access `innerHTML` pf specified DOM.

**Snippet sing page.$eval**

```
const myContent = await page.$eval('#myDiv', (e) => e.innerHTML);
console.log(myContent);
```

Works great with `jest-puppeter`.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use an asynchronous function evaluate.**

In my case, I was using puppeteer/jest and all await* solutions was trowing

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'
```

**innerHTML** with if statement was working for me(part of example)
I was searching the member's table for the first unchecked element

```
while (n) {

  let elementI = await page.$('div >' + ':nth-child(' + i + ')' + '> div > div div.v-input__slot > div');
  let nameTextI = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML , elementI);
  console.log('Mistery' + nameTextI);

  {...}
  i++;
  {...}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const html = await page.$eval("#myElement", e => e.innerHTML);
```